# How do I adjust the screen area for external monitors?

Tags: display

I don't know the exact wording for this. But basically my external monitor is too big for a certain game. Now I want the visible screen area to be smaller so that the game doesn't fill out the whole monitor. I want it smaller with a black border. Is that possible?
Thank you!

Comment: I *think* you are referring to "overscan" which is often used to scale smaller content on a TV to fill the screen. Some monitors/TVs have a menu setting to turn overscan on and off.

Comment: Are you sue the game doesn't have some resolution settings in its options?

Answer (score 0):

If the Mac recognises it as a 'TV' it will have an Underscan slider in the Displays control panel; otherwise, you'll need to find the control on the display itself.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

1. System preferences > Displays > Display Settings...
2. On the left, select the display you want to adjust the resolution for.
3. Click Scaled.

Now, for high resolution (think 4K) screens, you'll see pre-defined options (Larger text..... More Space).

If you don't see that, click Scaled.

Select the resolution that you want.

Optionally, press and hold Option on your keyboard and click scaled to reveal more resolutions (there can be a Show all resolutions option too).

Hope this helps